# Reintroduction of AR and GARCH processes in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop, return, time-series, volatility

I am trying reintroduce autocorrelation and heteroskedasticity to my simulated residuals. My simulated (standardized) residuals have the dimension (`horizon`, `nTrials`, `nIndices`). 
In order to calculate today's `mean` / `variance` (i.e. `t`), I need to use the last periods `mean` /`variance` (i.e. `t-1`) as an input. This is where I am stuck, I can't get this part of the code to run. I try to specify the use of last periods value by `{t-1}` (for example in `R_{t-1}`), but I receive the error message that `R_` is undefined.

I would be very happy about any hints on where I am going wrong here.

Carolin

```
for i=1:nIndices
  for j=1:nTrials
        for t=1:horizon
        R_t       = AA_alpha(i,:) + AA_beta(i,:) * R_{t-1} + sqrt(h_{t-1}) * Z(t,j,i);
        h_t       = AA_alpha1(i,:)+AA_GARCH(i,:)*variances(j,i)+AA_ARCH(i,:)*Z({t-1},j,i) + AA_LEVERAGE*ZCopy{t-1}  
        TR_t      = TR_{t-1} * exp(R_t);
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: You can't get the code to run or you don't know how to implement it?

Comment: I can't get the code to run. My implementation approach should be fine, but I am not 100% certain about the necessity and positions of the for loops.

Comment: In that case your question is ill-defined. Please update your question with a [**SSCCE**](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Hi Jean, thanks for your Tips! You were right, my question was not very well defined. I have tried to explain my problem in a more concise way now.

Comment: You still haven't posted a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) but I have tried to answer your question. See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are a bit confused about how matrix indexing works in Matlab.

If understood correctly, you have a variable `TR_t` with which you want to store the value for time `t`.
You then try to do the following:

```
TR_t      = TR_{t-1} * exp(R_t);
```

I will try to explain in words what you are doing here:

```
Set scalar 'TR_t' as follows:
> Take cell matrix 'TR_' and take cell t-1
> Then multiply with exp(R_t)
```

There are multiple problems with this statement. First of all, the variable `TR_` doesn't exist because you named it `TR_t`. Second of all, you are trying to index this scalar as if it is a cell matrix.

Before proceeding, I suggest you carefully study the [Matrix Indexing Article](http://nl.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html) and try again.

But just to help you understand what is going on quicker, here is a rewritten version of your code with explanation so you can follow what I'm doing.

```
// Variables that should already contain values before the loop starts
//**************************************************************************************
// >NAME<        >INITIALISATION EXAMPLE<              >DIMENSION<
//**************************************************************************************
AA_LEVERAGE = ?  //zeros(1,1);                         // Should be a scalar
ZCopy       = ?  //zeros(1, horizon);                  // (1 x horizon)
variances   = ?  //zeros(nTrials, nIndices);           // (nTrials x nIndices) 
AA_alpha    = ?  //zeros(nIndices, horizon);           // (nIndices x horizon)
AA_alpha1   = ?  //zeros(nIndices, horizon);           // (nIndices x horizon)
AA_beta     = ?  //zeros(nIndices, horizon);           // (nIndices x horizon)
AA_GARCH    = ?  //zeros(nIndices, horizon);           // (nIndices x horizon)
AA_ARCH     = ?  //zeros(nIndices, horizon);           // (nIndices x horizon)
Z           = ?  //zeros(nIndices, nTrials, horizon);  // (nIndices x nTrials x horizon)
SAVE_R      = zeros(nIndices, nTrials, horizon);       // (nIndices x nTrials x horizon)
SAVE_h      = zeros(nIndices, nTrials, horizon);       // (nIndices x nTrials x horizon)
SAVE_TR     = zeros(nIndices, nTrials, horizon);       // (nIndices x nTrials x horizon)

//**************************************************************************************
// START OF PROGRAM
//**************************************************************************************

for i=1:1:nIndices               // For i number of indices  (increment 1)
  for j=1:1:nTrials              // For j number of trials   (increment 1)

        R  = zeros(1,horizon);   // Re-initialise empty matrix (1 x horizon)
        h  = zeros(1,horizon);   // Re-initialise empty matrix (1 x horizon)
        TR = zeros(1,horizon);   // Re-initialise empty matrix (1 x horizon)

        for t=2:1:horizon        // For t number of horizons (increment 1) (start at 2)

           // Assumes R(1,1) is known
           R(1,t)  = AA_alpha(i,:)+AA_beta(i,:)*R(1,t-1)+sqrt(h(1,t-1))*Z(i,j,t);

           // Assumes ZCopy(1,1) is known
           h(1,t)  = AA_alpha1(i,:)+AA_GARCH(i,:)*variances(j,i)+AA_ARCH(i,:)*...
                     Z(i,j,t-1)+AA_LEVERAGE*ZCopy(1,t-1); 

           // Assumes TR(1,1) is known
           TR(1,t) = TR(1,t-1)*exp(R(1,t));
        end

        // Save matrices R, h and TR before end of inner loop otherwise ..              
        //  .. their information will be lost

        // For example, you can store their values as follows:
        SAVE_R(i,j,:)  = R(1,:);
        SAVE_h(i,j,:)  = h(1,:);
        SAVE_TR(i,j,:) = TR(1,:);

    end
end

// If all variables initialised correctly, should produce output
// Written for StackOverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30789390/
```

I hope that helps with your understanding of how Matlab works. If you want help with your code in general, consider posting your code on [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to get constructive criticism and suggestions for making your code better and cleaner.

Comment: Hi Jean, many thanks for your efforts! I have managed to implement your code now! I am still a quite inexperienced user of Matlab, so it is sometimes it a bit difficult to understand how matlab processes my matrices. Thanks a lot again for your help, I really appreciate it! Best, Carolin

Comment: @Carolin You are very welcome. Everyone has to start somewhere and you are clearly making the effort :) Good luck with your project and you can always ask more questions on SO!